# How to show news and query category with SqlAlchemy and flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a problem understanding how to link the data models in Flask with Jinja2. Could you explain, after I query the news and category what is the next step in displaying the data in HTML?

Below you have the News and Category Database Models.

```
class News(Model, ModelMixin, TimeStampMixin):
        __tablename__ = 'news'
    
        title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
        slug = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
        is_approved = Column(Boolean, default=False)
        _is_published = Column(Boolean, default=False)
        published_time = Column(DateTime)
        category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
        category = relationship(
            'Category', backref=backref('news', lazy='dynamic'))
        logo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('media.id'))
        logo = relationship('Media', foreign_keys=[
                            logo_id], cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan', 
                            single_parent=True)
        content = Column(UnicodeText)
        translations = Column(JSONB)
```

```
class Category(Model, ModelMixin, TimeStampMixin):
   __tablename__ = 'category'
   name = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
   def __repr__(self):
       return '<Category {}>'.format(self.name)
```

Form classes for News and Category:

```
def enabled_categories():
 return Category.query.all()
```

```
class AdminCreateNewsForm(FlaskForm):
        title = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
        upload_logo = FileField()
        is_published = BooleanField()
        is_approved = BooleanField()
        category_id = IntegerField(validators=[Optional()])
        content = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
        translations = JSONField()
        category = QuerySelectField(query_factory=enabled_categories,
                                    allow_blank=True)
    
class AdminUpdateNewsForm(FlaskForm):
        news_id = IntegerField(validators=[DataRequired()])
        title = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
        upload_logo = FileField()
        is_published = BooleanField()
        is_approved = BooleanField()
        category_id = IntegerField(validators=[Optional()])
        content = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
        translations = JSONField()
        category = QuerySelectField(query_factory=enabled_categories,
                                    allow_blank=True)
    
class AdminCreateCategoryForm(FlaskForm):
        name = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    
    
class AdminUpdateCategoryForm(FlaskForm):
        category_id = IntegerField(validators=[DataRequired()])
        name = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Comment: You query the table you want using `Category.query.all()` or `News.query.all()` and save the data in a list. Then, you pass the list of data in the `render_template()` view function as a parameter to have full access to the list in HTML. At that point, you can use Jinja2 to loop through the data and display it accordingly using the following block `{% for data in data.items %} <h1>data.name</h1> {%endfor%}`.

Comment: How to use Jinja2 when I click on name of category it query and show news in category?

Comment: That's not up to Jinja2 anymore! Use client-server communication like Ajax to do that kind of logic. When you receive the data from the server, in your `.js` script, target the component where the data should be displayed and pass the data in there.